# Animating Brownian particle movement with Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics, motion

I am attempting to create a Langevin simulation using python. Currently, I have code which updates the x and y coordinates of a single point based on the Langevin equations, and returns all of these positions in two arrays (x array and y array). I want to plot these changes in position as a moving scatter plot to show how the particle moves over time. How can I do this? Below is what I have so far:

```
# IMPORT STATEMENTS

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation



# CONSTANTS

v = 3.12e-5                # swimming speed of B. Subtilis [m/s]
M = 1                      # moment of B. Subtilis 
k = 1.38e-23               # Boltzmann constant [m^2kg/s^2K]
T = 293                    # Room temperature [K]
eta = 0.1                  # viscosity of water [Pa s]
a = 2e-6                   # spherical cell radius [m]
Dr = k*T/8*np.pi*eta*a**3   # rotational diffusion coefficient of B. Subtilis
 

# ADJUSTABLE PARAMETERS

B = 1       # strength of the magnetic field [T]
t = 100     # time over which motion is observed [s]
dt = 1      # time step between recorded positions
N = 1000    # number of cells 
 
#INITIAL CONDITIONS

theta_i = 0   # initial swimming orientation [radians]
xi = 0.001  # initial x position [m]
yi = 0.001 # initial y position [m]
x = []
y = [] 



# MAIN SCRIPT

for i in range (0,t,dt): 
    theta_j = (theta_i + M*B*np.sin(theta) + np.sqrt(2*Dr)*ksi)*dt
    xj = (xi + v*np.cos(theta))*dt
    yj = (yi + v*np.sin(theta))*dt 
    x.append(xj)
    y.append(yj)
    theta_i = theta_j
    xi = xj
    yi = yj
```

Comment: this looks good and clean, but you never call matplotlib! where are you running into trouble with it? are you trying to render an animation or provide a plot with a slider?

Comment: where do you plot it? Matplotlib has [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) to create animations and you could use it insitead of `for`-loop. You could find examples on Internet, with other questions on Stackoverflow, or in matplotlib documentation.

Comment: your code use variables `theta`, `ksi` which don't exist. `NameError: name 'theta' is not defined`. Put correct code.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:
https://github.com/mohammadjafariph/Brownian-Motion-Simulation
animated versions are available